# How to take form value for a session usage

Tags: php, session

I wouldlike that my SESSION retain a form value to another page.

My session code is:

```
<?php
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['zotikwa_iri']))
{
    header("location:./erreur.php"); // redirection
    exit; // arrêt du script
}

//The Session can show the page
?>

HTML
<form method="post" action="page2.php">
<input type="text" name="nickname" value=""/>
<input type="submit" name="bouton" value="Envoyer/>"
```

What code must I insert on my Mysql code and what code must I enter to the next page to show the form value in the previous page?

Note: I wouldlike to make only with SESSION.

Thanks

Comment: The form value wont be available until the form is submitted. Then `page2.php` will see the form values in `$_POST`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let form be in form.php

```
<?php 
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['boutom'])){
$_SESSION['nickname']=$_POST['nickname'];
}
?>
```

if you get session value of nickname in page2.php

```
<?php 
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['nickname'];
?>
```

if you want to destroy the session values session_destroy()

Comment: `$_POST['boutom']` you made a typo in the array name.